# jQuery styling if certain value requirements of a <td> are met

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, selector, html-table

I am learning jQuery atm and can't find my error here... actually the "problem" is quite simple

if a td cell with the class "red" has a value > 50, make it red

the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var n = $(".red").val();
    if (n > 50) {
    $(".red").css("color", "red");
} 
else {
    $(".red").css("color", "blue");
    }
});
```

do i have to use .each() here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `td` elements do not have the `val` property.

Need to use `.text` to get the text

Next use **parseInt** to convert it to a number

```
  if (n > 50) {
```

supposed to b e

```
  if (parseInt(n, 10) > 50) {
```

But because you are specifically setting each `td` to a specific color. You need to iterate over the list using `$.each`.  You can also use `.filter` as well.

```
// Will return all the `tds` with the value
var $red = $('.red').filter(function() {
               return parseInt( $(this).text(), 10) > 50;
           });
   // Set the red elements to color red
   $red.css('color', 'red');
   // All `.red` which are not in above selector are selected
   $('.red').not($red).css('color', 'blue');
```

**[Using Filter Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yFWEC/)**

**[Using Each Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yFWEC/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

Live demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/H8HVm/8/)

### HTML

```
<table id="theTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="red">5</td><td class="red">25</td><td class="red">50</td><td class="red">51</td><td class="notRed">105</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#theTable td.red').each(function(){
        var cellVal = parseInt($(this).text())
        if(cellVal > 50)
            $(this).css("background-color","red");
        else
            $(this).css("background-color","blue");
    });
});
```